# GeekTool-like app for resource charts/graphs?

Tags: macos, mac, geektool

Is there an app that's similar to GeekTool that will allow me to show graphical charts on my desktop showing resource usage (network i/o, disk usage, etc)? Specifically, I'm looking for something like Samurize for windows so I can in some way replicate the chart on the right-hand side of [this image](http://stuartwood89.deviantart.com/art/Transparence-95178742).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar using [Scruffy](http://scruffy.rubyforge.org/) to create pngs that I used for a desktop dashboard

Assuming you can pass a few numbers to a simple script, it should be easy to use scruffy to make a chart and then have that chart load from geektool.

Comment: Heh, you'd at least expect the examples to work on their website! I'll look into it though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the graph (filling bar portion):

You could do something similar in GeekTool using a desktop background (or even an alpha'd picture for the basic curves below the text element) and careful spacing (hello printf!) in either a script or the command you specify in GeekTool. Are you using GeekTool 2 or 3?

An example of spacing with printf:

```
printf "Line 1: %-50s\nLine 2: %50s\n" "Hello Left aligned" "World is right aligned"
```